# How to conver row based values to columns in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have a table in this format.

ROLES TABLE:

```
USERID  ROLE
------  -----
  1      A
  1      B
  2      B
  2      C
```

I want to create a report that will look like this.

```
USERID   A   B   C
------- --- --- ---
  1      Y   Y   N
  2      N   Y   Y
```

---

I tried using pivot, but not getting the exact result. Here is what I tried,

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT USERID,ROLE from ROLES) 
pivot(MAX(ROLE) for ROLE in ('A','B','C'))`
```

I need Y/N. I guess I need to use some decode fun instead of max(role).

PLEASE HELP.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be easily solvable without pivot just use case statement:

```
SELECT USERID,
       case when ROLE = 'A' then 'Y' else 'N' end,
       case when ROLE = 'B' then 'Y' else 'N' end,
       case when ROLE = 'C' then 'Y' else 'N' end
  FROM ROLES
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right about need for decode but you need them in different place

```
select user_id,NVL2(A,'Y','N') "A",NVL2(B,'Y','N') "B",NVL2(C,'Y','N') "C"from (
  select user_id,role from roles
  ) pivot(max(role) for role in ('A' as a,'B' as b,'C' as c));
```

Comment: tHIS IS NOT WORKING.